# Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: workflow, formula

Below is my workflow formula for evaluation.I am getting error saying "Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'"

```
(OR(!(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c)),"Booked"),(!CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c )),"Complete")),(!CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c )),"Terminated"))))
```

Comment: your formula looks correct. try to remove start and end bracket

Comment: I have removed small bracket from start and end.Still getting same error.

Comment: What is your rule criteria doing, it looks incorrect.

Comment: My rule criteria says that previous value of sales order status field should not equals "booked" or previous value of sales order status field should not contains  "Complete" word in picklist or previous value of sales order status field should not contain "terminated" word in picklist. sales order status field is picklist field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OR(!(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c))="Booked"),!CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c )),"Complete"),!CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c )),"Terminated"))
```

This worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Check this formula.

```
OR(!(CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c)),"Booked")),(!(CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c)),"Complete"))),(!(CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c)),"Terminated"))))
```

Comment: I dont want "contains" on 1st condition. i.e
 !(CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c)),"Booked"))

Comment: TEXT function has only one parameter. so you can't pass two parameter in TEXT function.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
OR(NOT(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c)),"Booked"),(NOT(CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c )),"Complete"))),(NOT(CONTAINS(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Sales_Order_DSR_Status__c )),"Terminated"))))
```